# Why growth of national income in current prices during inflation not measured in poor sections and poverty alleviation programs?

Tags: macroeconomics, inflation, gdp, economic-growth, national-income

Here 1) dwindles means reduce, smaller. Here is my doubt: If inflation fluctuates how can we use the word 'dwindles', what it means here? 2) Why the growth rate during inflation not measured in poor sections and poverty alleviation programs?[image]

Comment: “Fluctuates” seems to be a more appropriate word—the inflation rate shouldn’t just continually drop. Could you link the article in your post? Also what exactly is your question?

Comment: My best interpretation of this paragraph is that inflation has been hard to accurately measure in India and so it is hard to tell whether the real income levels for those in poverty have actually risen. Note I barely know anything about India or its economy.

Comment: It's not an article but it's from the text of economy book.

Comment: I will accept policymaking of inflation in India is tough because of the price rates fluctuates frequently. But here the author used "dwindles", I am confused, on what basis he used that word and why?

Comment: @kshikama Tell me in general. If a country's national income at current prices why cannot we measure growth in the income levels of the poor?

Comment: Just as @Brennan hints above, I think "dwindles" is a typo but it is hard to say without more context.

Comment: For example, if nominal income for those in poverty has grown by 100%, is it because they now have twice as much food to eat or because the price of food has doubled? The former would be a real impact while the latter would not be.